# Sort a Dataframe with a coumn from another Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have got two dataframes which looks like these.

```
df1 = 

Name    Order

John    2
Alice   3
Alisha  1
Mike    5
Katie   6
Steve   4


df2 = 

Name   Condition    Action

Mike    Stable      Out
Mike    Unstable    In
Steve   Stable      Out
Steve   Unstable    In
Katie   Stable      Out
Katie   Unstable    In
Alisha  Stable      Out
Alisha  Unstable    In
John    Stable      Out
John    Unstable    In
Alice   Stable      Out
Alice   Unstable    In
```

I want to sort df2 based on the order number given in df1.

I have tried using .index() and .reindex() but since there are repeating rows in df2, it is giving an error. 
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

The expected outcome should be something like this.

```
df_sort = 

Name    Condition    Action

Alisha  Stable       Out
Alisha  Unstable     In
John    Stable       Out
John    Unstable     In
Alice   Stable       Out
Alice   Unstable     In
Steve   Stable       Out
Steve   Unstable     In
Mike    Stable       Out
Mike    Unstable     In
Katie   Stable       Out
Katie   Unstable     In
```

Answer (score 1):

First add the `Order` column to df2:

```
df2['Order'] = df2.Name.map(df1.set_index('Name').Order)
```

Then do the sort and remove the Order column:

```
df2.sort_values('Order').drop('Order', 1)
```